# У кого есть материал как работать с Camera2API на русском?

Tags: java, android, камера

Мне необходимо сделать приложение с помощью Camera2API. Я нашел материал на английском, но моего уровня не достаточно, чтоб полностью понять... Может у кого нибудь есть материал на русском языке? Буду очень благодарен. Спасибо!

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прочтите эту статейку, думаю поможет вам http://sidstudio.com.ua/sidstudio-blog/razrabotka-android-prilozheniy-dlya-lollipop-ispolzuya-camera2-api-chast-1

Comment: ооо, Спасибо! то что нужно чтоб начать разбираться!

Comment: не за, что) удачи в ваших начинаниях)

Comment: А вы не подскажите что за прикол у них на этом сайте, они статью разбили на 3 части, и в конце первой части стоит ссылка типо продолжение читайте дальше. Нажимаю на эту ссылку а там ничего... У них на сайте есть 1-я часть и 3-я... второй нет? Может я где то не там посмотрел?

Comment: Я думаю, что статья не написана или находится в состоянии правки. Это момент времени когда опубликуют)

Comment: Так нет же... есть 3-я часть в начале которой написано "В предыдущих 2 частях мы рассмотрели основные принципы работы с камерой" , наверняка 2-я часть есть

Comment: Все, все 3 части сейчас опубликованы! Спасибо за инфу!

Comment: Поработал с этим пример итог такой: он не полный, функции сохранения картинки нужно дописывать и ошибки с форматом возникают.... но описание мне понравилось, чтоб в общем понять как что работает